# How to move the cursor to the next word in a rich text box in C#

Tags: c#

In C# how can I move the cursor to the next word in a rich text box?. for example

given the sentence

"He is a boy"

let's suppose that currently the cursor is positioned before "is" i.e. after "He" and I want to move it to the position before "a" i.e. after "is".

can `richtextbox.SelectionStart` be used for performing such an action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't mind using SendKeys then teh below example will achieve your requirement

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        SendKeys.SendWait("^{LEFT}");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        SendKeys.SendWait("^{RIGHT}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It worked!. Actually I'm developing a tagging utility for URDU text and after inserting the tag between two words, I wanted the cursor to move automatically between the next two. So, that the user be saved from the inconvenience of manually shifting the cursor

Answer (score 0):

You should trying finding the position of the next space using the .Find(Char) method.

```
int x = richtextbox.Find(' ');
richtextbox.SelectionStart = x;
richtextbox.Focus();
```

Don't have the possibility to test it, but i should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int curr = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;

int x = Regex.Match(richTextBox1.Text.Substring(curr), @"\s[^\s]").Index;

if (x != 0)
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = x + curr + 1;

richTextBox1.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to search a word; highlight it and move the cursor to the found word:
Note: The search button works as "per Click"; so for each click; it will search the next matching word in the richtextBox text document.

```
    // Search text and Highlight it (Per Click)
    // Manually add the "FindText"
    public int FindText(string txtToSearch, int searchStart, int searchEnd)
    {
        // Unselect the previously searched string
        if (searchStart > 0 && searchEnd > 0 && IndexOfSearchText >= 0)
        { rtb.Undo(); }

        // Set the return value to -1 by default.
        int retVal = -1;

        // A valid starting index should be specified.
        // if indexOfSearchText = -1, the end of search
        if (searchStart >= 0 && IndexOfSearchText >= 0)
        {
            // A valid ending index
            if (searchEnd > searchStart || searchEnd == -1)
            {
                // Find the position of search string in RichTextBox
                IndexOfSearchText = rtb.Find(txtToSearch, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                // Determine whether the text was found in richTextBox1.
                if (IndexOfSearchText != -1)
                {
                    // Return the index to the specified search text.
                    retVal = IndexOfSearchText;
                }
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    // Button to Perform the Search (By Click)
    private void btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;

        if (txt_Search.Text.Length > 0) startIndex = FindText(txt_Search.Text.Trim(), start, rtb.Text.Length);

        // If string was found in the RichTextBox, highlight it
        if (startIndex >= 0)
        {
            int x = rtb.Find(txt_Search.Text);
            rtb.SelectionStart = x;
            rtb.Focus();
            // Set the highlight color as red
            rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightYellow;  // Remove to avoid minor Bug
            rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;            // Remove to avoid Minor Bug
            // Find the end index. End Index = number of characters in textbox
            int endindex = txt_Search.Text.Length;
            // Highlight the search string
            rtb.Select(startIndex, endindex);
            // mark the start position after the position of
            // last search string
            start = startIndex + endindex;
        }

    }

    // TextBox to Search
    private void txt_Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start = 0;
        IndexOfSearchText = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Hope this helps.